# I need help putting all the logic statements in the correct order

Tags: vb.net

When I click the SEARCH button, this is what I would like to happen:

If the search field is empty, display a message saying "please enter student number".
If the search field isn't empty, search the database for the specific record matching what the user typed into the search field BUT making sure there are ONLY numbers in the search field, if a letter is found, display a message "numbers only", then search the db for the specific record. If the record isn't found, display a message saying "student does not exist". If the record is found, populate some fields with the data and then based off of what is in the record, enable some buttons and change their color.

That's all I want. And it does work...mostly. SOMETHING is out of order or in the wrong spot or something. I can't figure it out. The catch statement towards the bottom is commented out because it use to work but now it doesn't - again, something or some things are out of order. I'm not an advanced developer at all, go easy on me.

Here is my code for the click event of my search button:

```
If stunumtxtbox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a student number.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        stunumtxtbox.Select()
    Else
        Try
            Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=SERVER-NAME\IAWDB;Initial Catalog=iawdb;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True")
                connection.Open()
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
                ds.Tables.Add(dt)
                da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Student_Info WHERE studentId = '" & stunumtxtbox.Text & "'", connection)
                Dim count = da.Fill(dt)
                If count = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Student ID not found.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                Else
                    Dim g1 As List(Of String) = (From r As DataRow In dt Where r.Field(Of String)("g1") = "y" Or r.Field(Of String)("g1") = "n" Select r.Field(Of String)("g1")).ToList()
                    Me.G1Button.BackColor = If(g1.Contains("y"), Color.Green, If(g1.Contains("n"), Color.Red, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark))
                    Me.G1Button.Enabled = (g1.Count > 0)

                    Dim g2 As List(Of String) = (From r As DataRow In dt Where r.Field(Of String)("g2") = "y" Or r.Field(Of String)("g2") = "n" Select r.Field(Of String)("g2")).ToList()
                    Me.G2Button.BackColor = If(g2.Contains("y"), Color.Green, If(g2.Contains("n"), Color.Red, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark))
                    Me.G2Button.Enabled = (g2.Count > 0)

                    Dim af1 As List(Of String) = (From r As DataRow In dt Where r.Field(Of String)("af1") = "y" Or r.Field(Of String)("af1") = "n" Select r.Field(Of String)("af1")).ToList()
                    Me.AF1Button.BackColor = If(af1.Contains("y"), Color.Green, If(af1.Contains("n"), Color.Red, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark))
                    Me.AF1Button.Enabled = (af1.Count > 0)

                    Dim af2 As List(Of String) = (From r As DataRow In dt Where r.Field(Of String)("af2") = "y" Or r.Field(Of String)("af2") = "n" Select r.Field(Of String)("af2")).ToList()
                    Me.AF2Button.BackColor = If(af2.Contains("y"), Color.Green, If(af2.Contains("n"), Color.Red, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark))
                    Me.AF2Button.Enabled = (af2.Count > 0)

                    Dim af3 As List(Of String) = (From r As DataRow In dt Where r.Field(Of String)("af3") = "y" Or r.Field(Of String)("af3") = "n" Select r.Field(Of String)("af3")).ToList()
                    Me.AF3Button.BackColor = If(af3.Contains("y"), Color.Green, If(af3.Contains("n"), Color.Red, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark))
                    Me.AF3Button.Enabled = (af3.Count > 0)

                    Dim pp1 As List(Of String) = (From r As DataRow In dt Where r.Field(Of String)("pp1") = "y" Or r.Field(Of String)("pp1") = "n" Select r.Field(Of String)("pp1")).ToList()
                    Me.PP1Button.BackColor = If(pp1.Contains("y"), Color.Green, If(pp1.Contains("n"), Color.Red, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark))
                    Me.PP1Button.Enabled = (pp1.Count > 0)

                    Dim pp2 As List(Of String) = (From r As DataRow In dt Where r.Field(Of String)("pp2") = "y" Or r.Field(Of String)("pp2") = "n" Select r.Field(Of String)("pp2")).ToList()
                    Me.PP2Button.BackColor = If(pp2.Contains("y"), Color.Green, If(pp2.Contains("n"), Color.Red, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark))
                    Me.PP2Button.Enabled = (pp2.Count > 0)

                    Dim pp3 As List(Of String) = (From r As DataRow In dt Where r.Field(Of String)("pp3") = "y" Or r.Field(Of String)("pp3") = "n" Select r.Field(Of String)("pp3")).ToList()
                    Me.PP3Button.BackColor = If(pp3.Contains("y"), Color.Green, If(pp3.Contains("n"), Color.Red, SystemColors.ControlDarkDark))
                    Me.PP3Button.Enabled = (pp3.Count > 0)

                    EditStudentToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
                End If
                For Each DataRow In dt.Rows
                    If stunumtxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("studentId").ToString Then
                        fnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("firstName").ToString
                        mnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("midleInitial").ToString
                        lnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("lastName").ToString
                        addresstxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressStreet").ToString
                        address2txtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressOption").ToString
                        citytxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressCity").ToString
                        statetxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressState").ToString
                        ziptxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressZip").ToString
                        countrytxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressCountry").ToString
                        celltxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("contactcellphone").ToString
                        studentidtxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("studentId").ToString
                        TimeOwedTxtBox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("timeOwed").ToString
                        StudentNameTextBox.Text = lnametxtbox.Text & "," & " " & fnametxtbox.Text & " " & mnametxtbox.Text
                    Else
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
        Catch se As SqlException
            'If se.ErrorCode = -2146232060 Then
            'MsgBox("Enter numbers only.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            MsgBox(se.Message)
            'Else
            MsgBox(se.Message)
            'End If
        Finally
        End Try
    End If
```

Is there someone out there who may be a tadddddddd bit better at this then me, flip it all around for me and make it work and then help me understand the changes that were made and why they were made? haha I know, that is asking for a lot. I'm so close though...I think.

Comment: This is pretty broad for SO and not likely to remain open and would be better suited for CodeReview.  a) use parameters for queries b) those G1...PP3 blocks seem very over engineered and expensive way to just testg for a Y or N in `dt.Rows(0).Item("??")`  c) `Exit Sub` after the MessageBox at the top to reduce indentation.  (for starts)

Comment: yeah, I totally posted this in the wrong spot, my apologies. thanks for the pointers. @Plutonix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing you need is to test if the stunumtxtbox.Text contains a value that can be parsed as an Integer. the easy way is to use the Integer.TryParse method.
use it right after the test for an empty string. Also, your test for empty string can be better. use String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace method.
See this code example:

```
if Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stunumtxtbox.Text) Then
Dim i as Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(stunumtxtbox.Text, i) Then
        '' The string contains a valid integer, you can continue your code here.
    Else
        MsgBox("Enter numbers only.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        stunumtxtbox.Select()
    End If
Else
    MsgBox("Please enter a student number.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    stunumtxtbox.Select()
End If
```

As a rule, Exceptions should not be used for input validations.
**NEVER** use try...catch for things you can test in other simple ways.

One last thing: The loop is redundant. if you only have one row, there is no need to loop.

Comment: thank you for the tips - going to move this to the correct board.